# jQuery click() is not working in chrome and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Jquery to hide a div and show another div when a `<a>` tag is clicked. For some reason my code works in FF and IE, but it is not functional in chrome, opera or android browser.

To be more specific, the same jquery code is also used for some other `<a>` tags in the same page and that works, but not this one.

The `<a>` tag which doesn't work is inside a bootstrap dropdown menu.
I did a lot of research about the issue, but nothing really helped.

Here is the code

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#acc").click(function(g) {
        document.getElementById("a").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("b").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("c").style.display = "block";
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "main-dropdown" class = "dropdown">
     <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle headerbtn" data-toggle = "dropdown"><img src = "img/3-dots.png"/></a>
     <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
       <li>
          <a id = "acc" class = "acc" href = "#"><img src = "img/Settings.png"/>Settings</a>
       </li>
       <hr style = "color: #FFF; width: inherit; margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px !important;">
       <li>
          <a id = "l" class = "l" href = "#"><img src = "img/Logout.png"/>Logout</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </div>

<!--content-->
<div id = "a" style = "display: block;">
</div>
<div id = "b" style = "display: none;">
</div>
<div id = "c" style = "display: none;">
</div>
```

My Scripts are Linked at the end of the body and are ordered this way :

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/ajax_jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: fiddle would be helpful

Comment: Please create https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: There is no id as `acc_settings`

Comment: @Rayon: I am very sorry it is acc not acc_settings

Comment: Rayon Dabre's point is valid? where is acc_settings ?

Comment: You might also need `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @n01zw & Shashank: I never created a fiddle before, I am trying to do it now. There are many Js files linked in my code, and I really doesn't know how to get them into fiddle. I have no problem if you can view the code using Team Viewer. Thank you.

Comment: @Umer: I updated the code.

Comment: @Rayon: I used e.preventDefault(); & return false;. It did not help.

Comment: Working here: https://jsfiddle.net/j4p1bwh4/

Comment: Yeah it is working in the fiddle, but it is not working in my page for some odd reason. Will you be able to check it via team viewer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use `javascript:void(0)` to avoid conflict, and change your code to pure `jQuery`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#acc").click(function(g) {
       $('#a').css('display','none');
       $('#b').css('display','none');
       $('#c').css('display','block');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "main-dropdown" class = "dropdown">
     <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle headerbtn" data-toggle = "dropdown"><img src = "img/3-dots.png"/></a>
     <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
       <li>
          <a id = "acc" class = "acc" href = "javascript:void(0)"><img src = "img/Settings.png"/>Settings</a>
       </li>
       <hr style = "color: #FFF; width: inherit; margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px !important;">
       <li>
          <a id = "l" class = "l" href = "#"><img src = "img/Logout.png"/>Logout</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </div>


<!--content-->

<div id = "a" style = "display: block;">
a
</div>
<div id = "b" style = "display: none;">
b
</div>
<div id = "c" style = "display: none;">
c
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it, it still doesn't work on chrome, opera and mobiles.

Comment: maybe you have problem in other part, not on `code`,

Comment: Yeah it is working in the snippet, but it is not working in my page. My Js works in FF and IE but not Chrome

Comment: can we get the link so we can review it?

Comment: and i see you using `<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` try to use `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: it is on my local machine not hosted, and i tried the cdn too, no change.

Comment: yes, just click my profile and contact me there, i hope we dont obey the rules.

Comment: you give your `skype` so i can message your or anything.

Comment: maybe you have problem on `z-index`, just play it until you fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, when i change the Z-index of the dropdown-backdrop to -1 it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to attach an event to dynamic html element, 
you should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**Replace:**

```
$("#acc").click(function(g) {
    document.getElementById("a").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("b").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("c").style.display = "block";
});
```

**With:**

```
$('body').on('click', 'a#acc', function() {
    document.getElementById("a").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("b").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("c").style.display = "block";
});
```

Comment: is that works in android?